# Can't import Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm trying to import Alamofire inside my class but I obtain the error message `Cannot load underlying module for 'Alamofire'` . I did the same steps importing another library (SwiftyJSON), and it worked well. This is my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
end
```

Then I use `$ pod install` and I can find Alamofire as a module under Pods.

When I put in my class `import Alamofire`, it isn't found (but SwiftyJSON is).

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I had the same issue, the instruction at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40360050/1804274 successfully solved my problem.

Comment: Use .xcworkspace of your project after installing pods.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue was already reported on Github: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/441

Possible fixes mentioned there:

- Product -> Clean
- Restart Xcode

Comment: Product -> Clean worked, thanks, i'll accept the answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 5):

Anyone else having this issue could have forgot one step.

You may need to link Alamofire (or SwiftyJSON) to your project.

Project > Target > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, dude, you saved me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my ios version was different, in pod file

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

and I build the project using 8.0

After rebuilding my project with the pod specified version in my project, the error has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Alamofire documention and see if the requred xcode version is same as yours.