# What is the reason behind not importing Alamofire in my project?

Tags: swift2, cocoapods, alamofire

### I am making a demo of Alamofire using cocoa-pods.I am referring the tutorial "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire". I tried both manual and by sample procedure .But, when i am importing Alamofire,an error shows like "No such module 'Alamofire' ". So please help me to short out this issue.

[image]
[image]

```
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: What is your CocoaPods version? Update to CocoaPods 1.0

Comment: It always give me that message the first time i launch the workspace. Hit `Cmd + B` to build it once and it should be ok

Comment: Try close Xcode, go to your project directory run in console pod install. Then open project (YourProject.xcworkspace) and build. Eventually clean project from menu and delete Derived Data.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Terminal and `cd` to your project folder.
2. Create Podfile and add the code from https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire
3. In Terminal, run

   ```
   pod install
   ```
4. Close the project and open the newly created workspace: `projectName.xcworkspace`.
5. Run and build the project once.

Now it should be able to import.

Answer (score 1):

xcode need time to add Alamofire in to your project. 
My suggestion:

> Press `Command + Shift + R` to rebuild project.

Comment: @Harish: can i see your Podfile?

Comment: I solved this issue and the error was mismatching the version of Xcode and cocoapod version . My code was older version , when I updated this , . It is working fine for me . Thanks @ Tho Nguyen

Comment: that's right about the need for time. I went back to this project a day later, and after a Command + Shift + R cleared the error. It's a bit weird, but itt worked.

Answer (score -1):

When there is a mismatching version in your 'Podfile' against your Xcode Version, it would cause this issue.  For example:

My Xcode Version is 9.2 (see below)
[image]

Therefore my Podfile will need to include 9.2 in the platform section (see below on line 2)

[image]

After that, go back to your Terminal and recreate the '.xcworkspace' file by executing in the project folder:

```
pod install
```

Finally, open your '.xcworkspace' file in Xcode and click Build.

This should resolve the issue

Comment: That is the iOS version your project intends to support. Nothing to do with XCode version number.